# PG:Undefined object error when using activeimport with constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, upsert, activerecord-import

I am trying to do an upsert with ActiveImport. When running the import I am trying to pass it a named constraint in order to tell it when to update certain columns.

```
 User.import(
      @import_values,
      on_duplicate_key_update: {
        constraint_name: :index_users_on_uid_and_tenant_id,
        columns: %i[title location_id email active]
      }
    )
```

The code above is my import statement which is correct according to activeimport documentation. However, when I run this, I get PG:UndefinedObject error which shows the following:

```
Caused by PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  constraint "index_users_on_uid_and_tenant_id" for table "users" does not exist
```

However, in my schema.rb, on my users table schema, the constraint clearly exists:

```
 t.index ["uid", "tenant_id"], name: "index_users_on_uid_and_tenant_id", unique: true
```

and also, this returns true:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.index_exists?(:users, [:uid, :tenant_id]) => true
```

Any help as to why this is happening would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `unique constraint` implies the creation of a `unique index`, but not vice versa.

In your case, you created a `unique index` but not a `unique constraint`, so there's no constraint "index_users_on_uid_and_tenant_id", you can add a constraint, or use `conflict_target` to declare explicitly which columns the conflict would occur

```rb
User.import(
      @import_values,
      on_duplicate_key_update: {
        conflict_target: [:uid, :tenant_id],
        columns: %i[title location_id email active]
      }
    )
```